# Explorer: programmatically select file/directory with space in the path

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When I try to select a file or directory which has a space in its path in the Windows Explorer, it selects a completely different directory:

```
explorer.exe "/select,C:\Program Files\foobar"
```

I've tried it from Java with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
    "explorer.exe",
    "/select," + filePath
});
```

and with the above command line. In both cases, the same result. What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to quote the **path** (don't quote the `/select,` part).

Command line (tested):

```
explorer.exe /select,"C:\Program Files\foobar"
```

Java (not tested):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
    "explorer.exe",
    "/select,\"" + filePath + "\""
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution works only on command line, but not for Java.

Comment: @MikeL. The Java-part of the question is better suited for StackOverflow. Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746953/replace-space-characters-in-paths-with-what

Comment: OK, added following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624961/execute-command-with-correctly-escaped-paths

Answer (score 2):

This works fine in JDK6.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
"explorer.exe",
"/select,",
"\"" + filePath + "\""});
```

Comment: This is what actually works, and you can even omit the extra quotes around the path.